# Dropdown menu not displaying in handheld slide menu effect

Tags: mobile

I have a drop down menu on a Wordpress site tofballoons.ie, For some reason when I click then drop down it doesn’t load on a phone the way I assume it should, I can’t figure out what’s causing it, I have attached an image as to how I presume it should look and how It actually looks, any help would be much appreciated. (See Image 1) Notice the apple slide handheld menu, however my other drop down does not take the same effect (See Image 2).

[image]
[image]

Update:
Tracked down the actual file that was causing the issue, seems to be the selectWoo.js file
[image]

I then tried to dequeue the scripts with the following code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );

function agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'selectWoo' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'selectWoo' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'selectWoo');
    wp_deregister_script('selectWoo');

   }
}
```

but the code seems to have no effect? I have also found the same code solution on stack overflow as an accepted answer with numerous upvotes, maybe the code is outdated?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547598/how-to-unload-select2-script-styles-loaded-by-new-woocommerce-2-3-x/47314703

Comment: Is this your own theme that you authored?

Comment: It seems the dropdown for category is a custom made dropdown. Is it your own theme? Is jQuery UI being used? Or maybe a plugin that does some gui enhancement?

Comment: It’s a default theme, using storefront, the site was also designed with elementor which lets you make gui enhancements, even though the button is custom I’m still thinking that it should have inherited the same button style as the one I am trying to achieve? Also yes jQuery is being used

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am clearly a moron and forgot to clear my cache, the below code works perfectly

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts', 100 );

function agentwp_dequeue_stylesandscripts() {
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'selectWoo' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'selectWoo' );

    wp_dequeue_script( 'selectWoo');
    wp_deregister_script('selectWoo');

   }
}
```